# how to build a custom jquery ui file

Tags: javascript, jquery, build, google-closure-compiler

I forked the last release of jQuery ui from **[github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui)** and modified the code, and now I want to build it to create a compiled code like **[google's code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js)**.
I see there is a [`build.xml`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/build.xml) in the [`/build`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/build) directory, which says:

```
<!--
    jQuery UI Release!

    Call task called 'deploy-release' to build a full release.
    The release built will be stored on 'dist' dir.
-->
```

I dont know how to call the `deploy-release`. What should i do to generate the compiled javascript file?

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: under windows but i have cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like using what the process above...you can minify your JavaScript by cutting-and-pasting right into **[Google's Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)**.

Comment: it would be great but it seems that not working. I added the jquery-ui library and pasted my code into the textbox. but it seems something was wrong because the compiled code isn't working.

Comment: Works for me...all you have to do is replace everything below "ADD YOUR CODE HERE" and press compile.

Comment: this really works. i think i did something wrong. thanks for this easy solution!

Comment: Glad you liked it.  Of course, you'll want a more robust solution when you have LOTS of scripts.  When your able, take a look at the 'how do I start' section at: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

Answer (score 3):

The `build.xml` file looks like an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) file to me so try using Ant. Also, in [`build/release/prepare-release`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/release/prepare-release), we see this:

```
# Run the build
echo "Running build..."
ant
```

So it using Ant.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Build_From_Git). The build process is the same for jQuery UI.

Comment: With jquery i can run the `make` command because there is an exsisting makefile, but in jquery-ui there is no makefile. How can i build jquery-ui than?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Downloading_jQuery_UI)

From the root of the jquery-ui repo:

`cd build`

`ant`

Currently, you must have Java, Ant, and Node.js installed for it to work.  I recommend using NVM to install node.

Update: the link above is broken and new build instructions are in the README on github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui