# use jQuery to make div resizable without jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to to use jQuery UI resizable(), except I don't want to load the entire library for one feature.

Any ideas how to do this easily?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to build a custom jquery ui file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100915/how-to-build-a-custom-jquery-ui-file)

Comment: Tim, that topic is about minifying a JS file. I want to resize a div, though Kiiro has a good solution (though in some cases it wont work, like Google Maps)

Comment: The point is you can create a custom build of jQuery UI directly from the jQuery UI site. If you had been more explicit in your question about why that was not what you needed, I would not have raised the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use CSS resize?

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)

```css
#resizable {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="resizable">
  resizable div
</div>
```

Comment: Unbelievable that exists natively. I looked at this answer and thought huh, why don't I see any code in it until I tried the demo. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: I love the resize property, but there is no way to style the small handle in the bottom right. I use the resize property for textfields, but if you need to style the handle to be something like a full-height bar, you need javascript :-(